# How to change NSMenuItem Title (Login to Logout)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem

Im surprised that this hasn't already been asked:

But how does one go about changing the `NSMenuItem` title in a `NSStatusBar` menu. When a user logs in I want the menu item to say logout. I have tried creating an outlet to modify my `NSMenuItem` as a would a label or something.

`AppDelegate.h`

`@property (retain) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *loginItem;`

`AppDelegate.m`

`[loginItem setTitle:@"Logout"];`

But that didnt work.

The only thing that I was able to do was delete the old `NSMenuItem`, then add a new one, but it would just add it to the bottom. Is the only way to do this to remove every menu item then re-add them?? That seems very inefficient.

Comment: There's nothing in your example to suggest you're doing this incorrectly. But did you really connect your `IBOutlet` to the menu item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you describe should work, though, in general, keeping `IBOutlet`s for all your menu items can be tedious. (If your solution isn't working, make sure the `IBOutlet` is actually connected in the nib file, **and** make sure that you're setting the title at an appropriate time. If you're trying to set it in your controller's `init` method, for example, that's too early on, and the outlets haven't yet been connected up: move the method to `awakeFromNib` or similar.

A better approach in the long run is to use the [`<NSMenuDelegate>`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008605) protocol and [`NSMenuValidation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004173) (informal) protocol to update menu items dynamically (and lazily).

For example, define your controller class like the following:

```
@interface MDAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate>


@property (strong) NSStatusItem *statusItem;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusItemMenu;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *toggleLoginLogoutMenuItem;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *statusField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *progressField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator;

@property (assign) BOOL loggedIn;

- (IBAction)toggleLoginLogout:(id)sender;

@end
```

In the nib file, the `delegate` outlet of the `statusItemMenu` is set to the `MDAppDelegate` controller class. That assures that the `MDAppDelegate` class is in the responder chain and allow it to work with [validating the menu items](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000261-74653-BAJBGJHB).

Then you could implement your .m like the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    _statusItem.menu = _statusItemMenu;
    _statusItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"NSStatusItem", @"");
    [self updateLoggedInStatus];
}
- (void)updateLoggedInStatus {
    [self.statusField setStringValue:(self.loggedIn ? @"Logged in" : @"Logged out")];
}
- (IBAction)toggleLoginLogout:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(finishFakeLoginLogout:)
                         withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
- (void)finishFakeLoginLogout:(id)sender {
    self.loggedIn = !self.loggedIn;
    [self updateLoggedInStatus];
}
- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu {
#if MD_DEBUG
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
#endif
}
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {
#if MD_DEBUG
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
#endif
    SEL action = menuItem.action;
    if (action == @selector(toggleLoginLogout:)) {
        [menuItem setTitle:(self.loggedIn ? @"Logout" :@"Login")];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Sample project: http://github.com/NSGod/NSStatusBarFinagler

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to connect your menu item just try this..

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem = (NSMenuItem*) sender;
    NSString *menuString = menuItem.title;

    if ([menuString isEqualToString:@"Login"]) 
{

            [menuItem setTitle:@"LogOut"];
}
```

NSMenuItem *menuItem = (NSMenuItem*) sender;

```
     this line automatically collect the menu items in your app.
```

Comment: Not such a good plan if you want to localize the app for more than a single language.